# Objective c [self loadView] buggy on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

After searching all around the internet and looking at a myriad of forum and tutorials i can't find a way to fix my bug.

Here is the problem : in my ios app i'm loading a sub webView to see some stuf on the internet. To be able to come back to my app i set up a back button, that when i click it it load my RootViewController. But when i load my view controller from my subView i have a blank band that is comming just under my barButton header. if somebody already had this bug ?? it will be very appreciated to have some help or hint.

Here is a picture of my bug : http://s21.postimg.org/4al09vl7r/bug.jpg

Here is the code :

```
- (void) showBack;
{
  [self loadView];
  [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
}


- (void) makeRootButton
{
  UIBarButtonItem *rootButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hub"      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showBack)];
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = rootButtonItem;
  [rootButtonItem release];
}

- (void)showWebView;
{
  UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
  [self.view addSubview:webView];
  [self makeRootButton];

  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *defaults = [prefs stringForKey:@"myKey"];
  NSString *defaults2 = [prefs stringForKey:@"mySecondKey"];

  NSString *username = defaults;
  NSString *password = defaults2;

  NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

  NSString* body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login=%@&password=%@", username,   password];
  NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
  request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
  request.HTTPBody = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];

  [webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: you shouldn't call loadView explicitly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427053/calling-loadview-explicitly-good-bad

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can i do it differently, beacause when i call navigationController to push the RootViewController via self pointer i get a SIGABRT

Comment: you can create and make pushViewController in app delegate.

Comment: Okay i'm going right now on it ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider creating a new view controller for the web view and either pushing that view controller onto your navigation stack or presenting it (and adding some way to get back). Adding the web view as a subview does work but isn't so clean.

Your problem is that you shouldn't be calling `loadView` yourself (at all, and it isn't the correct way to approach the problem). You add the web view with `addSubview:`. The opposite of this is `removeFromSuperview` that you should be calling on the web view in your `showBack` method.

Comment: I think you right i have to do something clean, there is no reason to make dirty code. I will as you said do a ViewController for the WebView. Thanks for the answer sir.